# AS3: should private variables have an _

Tags: actionscript-3, syntax

I thought that AS3 now has private abilities added. So why should I still preface private variables with an underscore?

```
private var _privVar:String;
```

Comment: Did you find a correct answer?

Answer (score 10):

I make it a general rule in ActionScript 3 to follow Adobe's style.

Don't use underscores for private varibles unless your using a [getter or setter](http://qwickthoughts.blogspot.com/2007/07/getset-in-actionscript-3-explained.html). For example:

```
private var _foo:String;
public function get foo():String
{
    return _foo;
}
public function set foo(value:String):void
{
    _foo = value;
}
```

This example getter/setter is a little useless, as you could just make a public property that does the same thing. Only use a getter or setter when you need to do something **special** when you get or set the property. Even then, it's usually best just to create a public method instead.

Also another point. Personally I don't think it's a good idea to abbreviate your variable or method names. So instead of calling my variable **privVar**, I would call it **privateVariable**. This is especially true if you are using an IDE with autocomplete/suggest such as FlashBuilder(Flex Builder) or FlashDevelop.

Take a look at [Adobe - coding conventions and best practices](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Coding+Conventions) for more information.

Comment: If the getter and setter aren't doing anything special, it would be faster to just make the variable public. It's not going to hurt anyone.

Comment: exactly! My example was just a very simple one to express my point. It is quite rare that you would actually use getters or setters in AS3. Most of the time you make a public property or a public method.

Comment: Quite rare? Hardly. I guess it depends on how you code, but I code against interfaces quite a bit and getter/setter is the only way to achieve this.

Comment: To me, using getters and setters seems like a bad design decision. But I guess it makes sense to use them to enforce Interfaces. Anything other reason and getters and setters would be a lazy and messy choice.

Comment: If you go with public variables instead of getter/setter then anyone who later extends your class can't wrap functionality around the property without destroying it.  Not using getter/setter just screws the person that comes after you.

Comment: It's a matter of design pattern and team size. Working in larger teams and having anything as a public, creates such a big mess, that you can't even imagine. Public variables are hard to debug, and are not significantly faster than getter/setter. I see no gain in using public variables at all!
As Joel said, interfaces and getters/setters is one of the best core practices described in most of the Design Pattern books :)
HDave also gave a good example..

And about the underscore - it's again a matter of choice. Some people even prefix with 'm_' if it's member variable.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to. It's something that encourages readability, but is by no means mandatory. Entirely a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Using an underscore is just a convention. And I try to avoid them because it messes with my intellisense. I'm used to typing `obj.va` and hitting ctrl-space in flex builder to get `obj.variableName` - this doesn't work well with `_variableName`

Btw, does earlier versions of ActionScript require you to preface "private" variable names with an underscore?

Comment: It messes it, because it seems you don't get the idea. Using an underscore is because you want to mark a variable as a 'member' one. Which means it's private or protected. So you can't simply use it as obj.variable - this should be function or getter/setter, which of course doesn't start with underscore.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't abbreviate variables. it hardens readability and auto completion. On the other hand in my practice it's not a good thing to use built-in AS getters and setters with a syntax of `function set someVar ( value ) : void`. It hardens refactoring very much because when get in many time by just not knowing that some variable is a setter or getter.

In where I used to work we used Java Beans property access convention like `function setSomeVar ( value ) : void`. Of course, because it's not a common use in AS community, such IDE's like FlashDevelop doen't support such getters and setters generation.